# C++ simple mutex using atomic_flag (code not working)

Tags: c++11, concurrency, atomic, memory-model

This is an exercise of using atomic_flag with acquire/release memory model to implement a very simple mutex.
There are THREADS number of threads, and each thread increment cou LOOP number of times. The threads are synchronized with this simple mutex. However, the code throws exception in thread.join() function. Could someone please enlighten me why this does not work? Thank you in advance!

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class mutex_simplified {
private:
    atomic_flag flag;
public:
    void lock() {
        while (flag.test_and_set(memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void unlock() {
        flag.clear(memory_order_release);
    }
};

mutex_simplified m_s;
int cou(0);
const int LOOP = 10000;
const int THREADS = 1000;
void increment() {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
        m_s.lock();
        cou++;
        m_s.unlock();
    }
}

int main() {
    thread a(increment);
    thread b(increment);
    vector<thread> threads;

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
        threads.push_back(thread(increment));

    for (auto & t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    assert(cou == THREADS*LOOP);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you join threads `a` and `b`? Also you need to initialize `atomic_flag` explicitly.

Comment: @Ivan Thank you! Your suggestions fixed my bug. For some reason, I am not able to accept your answer because the checkbox next to your answer is missing... I only see a flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not joining threads `a` and `b`. As the result, they might be still running while your program is finishing its execution.

You should either add `a.join()` and `b.join()` somewhere, or probably just remove them as the assertion in your `main` function will fail if you keep them.

Another issue is that you need to explicitly initialize `atomic_flag` instance in your mutex constructor. It might not cause issues in your example because global variables are zero-initialized, but this might cause issues later.